# Node.js Library Supporting SNMP

Tags: node.js, snmp

I am looking for a 3rd party NodeJS library that supports SNMP Traps/Notifications. Wishfully, it works on Linux running on a VM.

Thanks!

Comment: http://bit.ly/1AVkv2f Have you tried this...?

Comment: So not only have you not read [what questions to ask on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), you have also failed to read [how to behave on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) (not to mention your behaviour would hardly be tolerated anywhere else)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you are looking for:  [node-snmpjs](https://github.com/joyent/node-snmpjs)